# How to install external python libraries in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When I was some pyspark code, it required to me to install a Python module called fuzzywuzzy (that I used to apply the leiv distance)

This is a python libraries and seems that pyspark doesn't have the module installed... so, How can I install this module inside Pyspark??

Comment: A little googling never hurt anyone https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `pip` as normal, with the caveat that Spark can run on multiple machines, and so all machines in the Spark cluster (depending on your cluster manager) will need the same package (and version)

Or you can pass zip, whl or egg files using `--py-files` argument to spark-submit, which get unbundled during code execution

Comment: Hi! you mean "spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('fuzzywuzzy.zip')" I tried, but I had other problems -> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o200.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 59) (LAPTOP-FHPP0Q98 executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset

Comment: Ideally you'd pass at the CLI rather than in code, but that'll do the same thing. Anyway, `HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset` error is unrelated to Python packages

Comment: Alright, but I had this problem after inserting that line of code

Comment: Understandable, but Spark requires Hadoop libraries, so there are other cases where you'd see the same error. So, have you tried setting those values?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to answer I solved installing again spark 'cause miss the libraries that you mentioned! Thanks for the support